# How do I create a column chart with an aggregated column

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, histogram, seaborn

I have two columns customer_id and revenue and I'm trying to figure out how to use matplotlib (or seaborn) to create a histogram/bar/column chart that has an aggregated column on the right. Everytime I change the range it just cuts off those values above my max range. Instead I want there to be a bin that is the count of instances above that max value.

For the example chart linked below, if I define my range as 0-1558, I want there be a column that counts the instances of all values $1558 and above and display that as a column.

[Example Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrdeu.png)

Comment: What data structure do you use for your project? Pandas dataframe? Numpy array? List of lists?

Comment: @DYZ I'm using pandas dataframe, reading from a CSV.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the width of histogram columns all the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080028/how-to-make-the-width-of-histogram-columns-all-the-same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same concept as @DYZ, but my code ended up being:

`df.ix[df.revenue > limit, 'revenue'] = limit`

Answer (score 0):

Cap the values above the limit:

```
df[df['revenue']>limit] = limit
```

Now, plot the histogram.